# Why did Jesus say his testimony is not valid in John 5:31 and in John 8:14 Jesus says his testimony is valid?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, son

Why did Jesus say his testimony is not valid in John 5:31 and in John 8:14 Jesus says his testimony is valid?

> John 5:31 - If I bear witness concerning Myself, **My testimony is not
> true.**
>
> John 8:14 - Jesus answered and said to them, "Even if I am bearing
> witness concerning Myself, **My testimony is true**, because I know
> from where I came and where I am going. But you do not know from where
> I come or where I am going.